# django get values from a model field

Tags: python, django, model, view

I have model :

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0) # Field that denotes the no of vote for particular question

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

And my view:

```
def VoteCountView(request, pk):

    ques = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    cpk = ques.category.id
    valid_user = ques.user.username

    if request.user.is_general_user:
        if request.user.username == valid_user:
            messages.warning(request, "You cannot vote your own question")
            return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
        else:
            vote_limit = Question.objects.values_list("vote", flat=True).filter(pk=pk).filter(user=request.user)#[0][0]
            print "vote count"
            print vote_limit
            if vote_limit < 1:
                vote_count = ques
                print vote_count.user
                count = vote_count.vote
                count +=1
                vote_count.vote = count
                vote_count.user = request.user
                print vote_count.user
                vote_count.save()
            else:
                messages.warning(request,"You cannot vote twice")
                return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
    else:
        messages.warning(request,"You are not allowed to vote a question")
        return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
```

Here what I want is other user can vote the question except the user who posted the question. When other user vote the question it says list index out of range. Can I achieve this from this model or I have to make separate model for vote.

Also if the user that are not logged in or not general use, if the vote it says user object has no attribute is_general_user??

Can anyone help me on this ???

Comment: why you get "list index out of range": because your queryset returns no results

Comment: "if the user that are not logged in or not general use, if they vote it says user object has no attribute is_general_user"  ...yes, obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of things to optimize:

instead of

```
ques = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
```

better use `get_object_or_404(Question, id=pk)`. you never know what happens in future...

before you do `if request.user.is_general_user:` you need to check if user is authenticated:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    if request.user.is_general_user: 
        #....
```

this way, you make sure that you are playing with Authenticated User and not with Anonymous User (the one how is not logged in). And this may solve your other `list index out of range` problem, because now `request.user` in your filter is an authencated one who is also in db.

you can write your query also this cleaner way:

```
vote_limit = request.user.question_set.values_list("vote", flat=True).filter(pk=pk)#[0][0]
```

i dont know what you mean by `[0][0]`, if want to get the latest Question, you can do:

```
.order_by('-id')[0]
```

instead of `[0][0]`

**UPDATE**: i didnot go into what you really want into context. I just tried to fix the bugs.

Comment: `request.user.question_set.values_list("vote", flat=True).filter(pk=pk)` is a good translation of what the OP coded... but it makes no sense to do that in context of what OP is trying to achieve. (also that particular item was already retrieved earlier by `ques = Question.objects.get(id=pk)`)  ...I think what OP really wants is something based on `Question.objects.exclude(user=request.user)`